# Read PLC parameters

Tags: java, plc

I need to read all parameters on a data block. I can read Family (like pool, math, control, ...) and mc7 size that show total size of block by `moka7` (a java version of snap7), but now, I need to load all parameters inside a data block.

On attachment you can see all parameters of a MATH data block, show by DB param utility in `SIMATIC MANAGER (STEP 7)`

[image: sample of data parameters]

Comment: What have you tried to load the parameters inside the data block? What problems have you encountered? Can you also post your current code?

Comment: do you know snap7? moka is java version of snap7 and I use it to read plc data

Comment: I have no any problem when read data from plc. I only need to can read data block structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!

After a week  searching about this question, I open files in simatic project one by one, and find `SUBBLK.DBF and DBT` and `BAUSTEIN.DBF and DBT` inside `ombstx` folder. these are two [dBase](http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/DBF-dBASE-file) files.

with these 2 file you can know any information about all objects like FB, FC, DB and ..., with enough information about that.

After this exploration!, I found this links with continues search that can show better information about 2 above files.
[project bloc list in excel file](https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/ww/en/posts/project-bloc-list-in-excel-file/35282/?page=0&pageSize=10) and [THIS](https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/ww/en/posts/s7-project-and-visual-basic-connectivity-with-simatic-type-library-v-1-0-s7abatcx-dll/23133/?page=0&pageSize=10)

finally, you can use [JavaDBF](https://github.com/albfernandez/javadbf) library to read data from your DBF and DBT files :) (block's structure stored in DBT files) .